# Highchart treemap legends do not show specific legend

Tags: highcharts, legend, treemap

How can I hide a specific legend in my highchart treemap?

I have a treemap with 4 legends but I always want to show only 3 legend & hide or do not show 1 particular legend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Highcharts 'afterGetAllItems' event, you can modify the number of items in legend:

```
var H = Highcharts;

H.addEvent(H.Legend, 'afterGetAllItems', function(e) {
    e.allItems.splice(1, 1)
});
```

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/m0587v4q/

Docs: https://www.highcharts.com/docs/extending-highcharts/extending-highcharts